# Limiting distribution of a sequence of Poisson RVs

Tags: statistics

Suppose that each random variable $B_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$ in an iid sequence of random variables $B_n$ has a Poisson($i$) distribution. How could I find the limiting distribution of $G_n = \sqrt{B_n}$?

My first idea was to see if $B_n$ converges in distribution to some limiting distribution $B$, and then use that fact to show that $G_n$ converges to some limiting distribution $G = \sqrt{B}$. However, $B_n$ does not converge to anything, so I can't use that line of reasoning.

How could I approach this problem?

Comment: If the $\text{“}\,$limiting distribution $B\,\text{''}$ existed, what would be meant by the notation $\text{“}\sqrt B\text{''?} \qquad$

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity. In particular, I'm trying to find (if it exists) a limiting distribution $G$ for $G_n$, relying on the fact that if an iid sequence $X_n$ converges in distribution to some RV $X$, and a function $f$ is continuous on the support of $X_n$, then $f(X_n)$ converges to $f(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{B_i - i}{\sqrt i} \overset{\mathcal L}\longrightarrow N(0,1) \text{ as } i\to\infty.
$$
$$
f(B_i) \approx f(i) + f'(i)(B_i-i)
$$
$$
\frac{f(B_i) - f(i)}{ f'(i) \sqrt i} \approx N(0,1)
$$
$$
f(x) = \sqrt x
$$
$$
f'(x) = \frac 1 {2\sqrt x}
$$
$$
f'(i)\sqrt i = \frac 1 2
$$
$$
2(\sqrt{B_i} - \sqrt i\,) \approx N(0,1)
$$
Notice that this implies there is no limiting distribution of $\sqrt{B_i}.$ There is, however, an "asymptotic distribution" of $\sqrt{B_i}.$ It is interesting that the variance of $\sqrt{B_i}$ remains bounded as $i$ grows.

The argument above is not fully rigorous; you need to cite the appropriate theorems. They can be found in Serfling's *Limit Theorems of Mathematical Statistics*.

Comment: Upon looking up the definition of "asymptotic distribution", I realized that we might be using different terminology. I'm looking for an asymptotic distribution in the sense that you're using the term.